# react js importing multiple component from a single jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import multiple component which is in one single jsx file in the main js file

This question has been already answered but without example here [How to import and export components using React + ES6 + webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack)

My code is as below

App3.jsx file

```
import React from '../node_modules/react';


export default class App2 extends React.Component {
   render() {
       var i = 1;

       var myStyle = {
         fontSize: 25,
         color: '#FF0000'
       }

      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <p data-myattribute = "somevalue">This is the content!!!</p>
            <h1>{1+1}</h1>
            <h1>{i = 1 ? 'True!' : 'False'}</h1>
            <h1 style = {myStyle}>Header</h1>
            { /*gsadjshds */ }
         </div>
      );
   }
}




export default class App3 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <Content/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default class Content extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <p>The content text!!!</p>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

And main.js file as below

```
import React from './node_modules/react';
import ReactDOM from './node_modules/react-dom';
import App  from './js/App.jsx';
import App1  from './js/App1.jsx';
import {App2, App3}  from './js/App3.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
ReactDOM.render(<App1 />, document.getElementById('app1'));
ReactDOM.render(<App2 />, document.getElementById('app2'));
ReactDOM.render(<App3 />, document.getElementById('app3'));
```

But i am getting below errors

Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Offtopic: `<h1>{i = 1 ? 'True!' : 'False'}</h1>` this is probably wrong, unless you really want to assign `1` to `i`.
`

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that you have more than one `export default`. Try using regular exports for all you components.

Comment: It worked I used regular exports for all the components and now the code is working Thank you very much Gilad. Sorry for my late response I had to go out to get some work done.

Answer (score 4):

May because you are using multiple `export default` in a single file. React treats `export default` like the `main` class/function of the file and will conflict with other `main`s upon export. Your code should probably be

```
import React from '../node_modules/react';


class App2 extends React.Component {
render() {
   var i = 1;

   var myStyle = {
     fontSize: 25,
     color: '#FF0000'
   }

  return (
     <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <h2>Content</h2>
        <p data-myattribute = "somevalue">This is the content!!!</p>
        <h1>{1+1}</h1>
        <h1>{i = 1 ? 'True!' : 'False'}</h1>
        <h1 style = {myStyle}>Header</h1>
        { /*gsadjshds */ }
     </div>
  );
  }
}




class App3 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <Content/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <p>The content text!!!</p>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export { App2, App3 };
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
import component_exported_as_default, {component_1, component_n} from './path/filename'
```

> Basically you need to import the components which are **not exported by default** inside the curly braces **{}**. For example consider the code below (i've considered the functional component but the import strategy is same for class based components too).

**components/my_component.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function component_exported_as_default(){
    return <p>Exported by default</p>
}

export function component_1(){
    return <p>Component_1</p>
}

export function component_2(){
    return <p>Component_2</p>
}
```

**App.js**

```
import component_exported_as_default, {component_1,component2} from 'components/my_component.js'
function App(){
   return(
      <div className="APP">
         <component_exported_as_default>
         <component_1>
         <component2>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Hope this helps. ;)