# How to call React api component into main component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I have written some API call in component and when I try to add the imports in my main component it shows following error
ERROR in ./src/containers/Ready_bricksapi.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports' in 'D:\Brickzle (1)\src\containers'

@ ./src/containers/Ready_bricksapi.jsx 1:0-65

@ ./src/containers/homepage.jsx

@ ./src/containers/app-route.jsx

@ ./src/entry-points/client.jsx

@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/entry-points/client.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export  class ReadyBricks extends Component {
   Constructor(props) {
     Super(props);
     this.setState = {
       bricksList: []


     };


   }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.readyBrick();
  };

     readyBrick() {
     console.log("inside get api");
     const url = '\'http://10.10.1.42:8070/api/user/brick/getBrickList?id=0\'';
       fetch(url, {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'auth':'sdf345dvdfg4dfgdf435fghfhfg45123'
         },
       })
         .then(function (response) {
           let bricksList=response.results;
           return bricksList;
           console.log(bricksList);
         })

         .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
         });





     }


  render() {
    const ReadyBricks = this.state.bricksList.map((item) => {
      return <div className="col-xs-12">
        <div className="col-xs-6">
          <p>Ready Brick Arts </p>
          {item}
        </div>
      </div>
    });


  }

 }
```

now my question is how to add this jsx file into my components

Comment: @shota can u please suggest some links for react api call

Comment: Please look for a React beginner tutorial, it will show you how.

Comment: can u please suggest some links , because that will be payable

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'payable' - are you offering to pay for advice? I'm not really interested in that.

Here is how you do it. On a page somewhere (usually index.html) you nominate a HTML element to receive the top level `render()` from React.

Let's say your HTML looks like this

```
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

and in your script you do this:

```
React.render(
    <ReadyBricks/>,
    document.getElementById('myDiv')
);
```

So that will render your `ReadyBricks` component into the `myDiv` div.

But if you don't know that already, and you want to build things with React, then you really do need to do a course.