# When use curly brackets on react-native export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After create some components and export it in the logs show:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

Some answers that i read about this topic complicated more about import and export on react-native.

so, doubt is:

if the component is not dynamic export with curly brackets?
and if dynamic export without curly brackets and with default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack

Comment: @Isaac no is not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**here is the answer**

Exporting without default means it's a "named export". You can have multiple named exports in a single file. So if you do this,

```
export class Template {}
export class AnotherTemplate {}
```

then you have to import these exports using their exact names. So to use these components in another file you'd have to do,

```
import {Template, AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```

Alternatively if you export as the default export like this,

```
export default class Template {}
```

Then in another file you import the default export without using the {}, like this,

```
import Template from './components/templates'
```

There can only be one default export per file. In React it's a convention to export one component from a file, and to export it is as the default export.

You're free to rename the default export as you import it,

```
import TheTemplate from './components/templates'
```

And you can import default and named exports at the same time,

```
import Template,{AnotherTemplate} from './components/templates'
```

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37863284/218196 , so pretty much a duplicate? The overall theme is "how to import/export values"

Answer (score 1):

You should use the curly braces for import a module only if the module is just exported, and if the module is exported as default exported module, you should import it without curly braces.

Exported module example 1:

```
...
export SomeModule;
```

then you should import it as below:

```
import { SomeModule } from 'someWhere'
...
```

Exported module example 2:

```
...
export default SomeModule;
```

then you should import it as below:

```
import SomeModule from 'someWhere'
...
```