# Adding values to a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

C# developer here.
I would like to ask how can I add a values to a class.

This is my class:

```
class Players {
    constructor(playerOne, playerTwo) {
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
    this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    }
}
```

Here I call it's constructor:

```
handleClick() {
this.setState({ clicked: true });
Players(
  document.getElementById("Select_Player1").value,
  document.getElementById("Select_Player2").value
);
console.log(Players.playerOne);
console.log(Players.playerTwo);
}
```

And I export it at the end of file:

```
export { Players };
```

After clicking on button which execute `handleClick()` application return an error: `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`.

Comment: You need to use `new Players(...)`

Comment: Use `new Players(...)`.

Comment: Note: Apart from the error, your code doesn't looks like React way.. If you share the code, we can guide you..

Comment: This is not the react way. You don't need to get the `value` like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.playerOne` and `this.playerTwo` isn't static!

so for use non static:

```js
class Players {
    constructor(playerOne, playerTwo) {
        this.playerOne = playerOne;
        this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    }
}
var myP = new Players(
  'test1',
  'test2'
);
console.log(myP.playerOne);
console.log(myP.playerTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And use static:

```js
class Players {
    static setPlayers(playerOne, playerTwo) {
        this.playerOne = playerOne;
        this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    }
}
Players.setPlayers(
  'test1',
  'test2'
);
console.log(Players.playerOne);
console.log(Players.playerTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Done, thanks! Would you help me with how can I get the values from this class in different file? I've exported it with `export { Players };` and then imported with `import { Players } from "./Authentication";` and I want to call `playerOne` from this class. `console.log({ Players.playerOne });` doesn't work.

Comment: @Chyu try use "export default class Players"  and "import Players". more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack anyway please accept my answer :)

Comment: That's better. But I still can't get `playerOne` or `playerTwo`. And it's set: https://imgur.com/1OIITcI

Comment: use static solution.

Comment: Solved. I've been using `console.log({ Players.playerOne })` instead of `console.log(Players.playerOne)`.