# Adding to component from another component using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `footer` that I created in `App.js` and now I have another component called `KokPlayer.js` and I want to add buttons from `KokPlayer.js` to the `footer` in `App.js`.

How can I do that?

**App.js**

```
render() {
  const { expanded } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <nav
        className="footer navbar navbar-light bg-success mb-auto"
        ref="footerRef"
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**KokPlayer.js**

```
render() {
  // Add this block to footer
  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "block", margin: "0 auto", verticalAlign: "middle" }}
    >
      <Button onClick={this.play} className="mr-3">
        play()
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.pause} className="mr-3">
        pause()
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.toggleFullScreen} className="mr-3">
        FullScreen()
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to import the component in `KokPlayer.js` to `App.js` and render the component as a child to the footer.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack

Comment: Then you might want to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and move the rendering of the buttons from `KokPlayer` to the footer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand what you wrote in the comments, you can pass a prop to KokPlayer component then you can hide the elements that you don't want to show them up in App.js

in **App.js**

```
import KokPlayer from './KokPlayer' // KokPlayer location
```

....

```
render() {
  const { expanded } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <nav
        className="footer navbar navbar-light bg-success mb-auto"
        ref="footerRef"
      />
     <KokPlayer showButtonsOnly={true} /> // the buttons here
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**KokPlayer.js**

```
render() {
  // Add this block to footer
  return (
   <div>
     {!this.props.showButtonsOnly && <div> // it wouldn't be shown in App.js
        Screen Here 
     </div>}
    <div style={{ display: "block", margin: "0 auto", verticalAlign: "middle" }}
    >
      <Button onClick={this.play} className="mr-3">
        play()
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.pause} className="mr-3">
        pause()
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={this.toggleFullScreen} className="mr-3">
        FullScreen()
      </Button>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But this solution does not pass on the functions of the buttons which are defined in `KokPlayer.js`,  this.play and so on

Comment: Yes, it's doesn`t pass the functions of the buttons but the buttons functions are working. if you want to pass the functions to App.js component you can use Lift state up