# Language object prop to pass in the react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a demo using a tutorial that i have found.

This is the demo => https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-monad-otv0g?file=/src/language.js

In `App.js` the sidebar is receiving the array of objects as props, it all works fine

```
  const sidebaritems = [
    {
      name: "first",
      label: "First",
      items: [
        { name: "sublink2", label: "SubLink 1" },
        { name: "sublink3", label: "SubLink 2" }
      ]
    },
    "divider",
    {
      name: "second",
      label: "Second",
      items: [
        { name: "subLink 1", label: "SubLink 1" },
        { name: "subLink 2", label: "SubLink 2" }
      ]
    },
    "divider",
    {
      name: "third",
      label: "Third"
    }
  ];




<SideBar items={sidebaritems} />
```

I want now to use an external data language file that i import where i have other translations and also `sidebaritems` to pass, so i have created `language.js` and imported in the `App.js`

```
import dataForTexts from "./language.js";
```

My question is, how can i pass from `language.js` the same  `sidebaritems` in my `sidebar` component in `app.js`

Comment: you want to merge both the `sidebaritems` and the list from the language.js ?

Comment: only passing the sidebaritems or if you have a better way to do, you can show me

Comment: It's not a default export so you need `import { dataForTexts } from "./language.js";` (note the curly braces). Then use `<SideBar items={dataForTexts.sidebaritems} />`

Comment: i get this => Cannot read property 'sidebaritems' of undefined, if you can post your answer and show me in the demo, i accept it

Comment: Duplicate: [How to import and export components using React + ES6 + webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a named import to import your `dataForTexts` . So change your import statement as

```
import { dataForTexts } from "./language.js";
```

Now pass the `sidebaritems` as

```
<SideBar items={dataForTexts.sidebaritems} />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need this. As items, you just need to pass your data from language.js (dataForTexts)
[image: gg]

Comment: This won't work (see my comment). Also, please don't post images of code; post code.