# I made an API call fetching data from it on a React component and passed it on to a state. I want to use the same data on another component too

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says, I have fetched data from API on a component. I want that component to just act like a "store" for the fetched data, meanwhile, rendering those data on to another component. How do I do that if that's possible?

This is Fetch.js which is supposed to get data from the API  and store it in `person` of `state`. Now I want to break the object stored in `person` and separate into different `var` like for `fname`, `lname`, etc.

```
import React from "react";
export default class Fetch extends React.Component {
state = {
loading: true,
person: null,
 };

async componentDidMount() {
console.log("mounted");

const url = "https://api.randomuser.me/";
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
this.setState({
  loading: null,
  person: data.results[0],
});
}

render() {
return console.log(this.state.fname);
 }
}
```

Now that everything said above is done, I have another file `Main.js` where I want to display the fetched data (broken into each variable like fname,lname) from `Fetch.js`.

```
import React from "react";
export default class Main extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
      <div>Loading</div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        Name: {this.state.fname} {this.state.lname}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
       );
      }
     }
```

Comment: you pass those data via props then you can access those state data in the props.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that data in properties from a parent component to children:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const data = fetch(...);

  return <ChildComponent data={data} />
}
...
function ChildComponent(props) {
  const data = props.data;

  ...
}
```

But if you might need that data in many components (or there are a bunch of layers to the child component) it would be way more convenient to use React's Context for this purpose: https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I mean sharing the data in two different components in two different files. 
For example: 
I have a file `Fetch.js` where I have fetched data of a person (say) using an API. Now, I want a state to store the data in `Fetch.js` itself but render the data from state of `Fetch.data` in a different component of a separate file, say `Index.js` because I want `Fetch.js` to act like a "backend" while stying the `index.js`.

Comment: If I got you right, all you need to do is just import the child component in the parent file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack

Comment: or if you're using both components in another file, you should import them both. In this case you'll have to access the ParentComponent's children via props https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren

Comment: IDK ma'am I mean this is the third day I started learning react and wanted to head on creating my own project, got stuck with this thing.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this article useful: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-pass-data-between-react-components

Comment: I read it as well but I do not think I addressed my problem. Can we connect somewhere so I could send you my code and seek your assistance? That'd be helpful.

Comment: You can share your code right in the body of your question above. That will be helpful both for those who'll try to help you with it, and those who'll use this question as an information source in the future.
You can get more info about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please check the update. I have added my code above.